# How to prevent make to run $(shell command) too early

Tags: makefile

I want to create a file during a rule of a makefile,
At the end of the rule, I want to run a shell command for the file by using `$(shell xxx)` function of make.

This is simplified example makefile for showing the problem:

```
test:
        @echo 123 >> file
        @cat file
        @echo "File: $(shell cat file) "
```

I expected that the last line of the makefile would print: `File: 123`

Instead it looks like that make runs `$(shell cat file)` before other lines of the makefile:

```
> rm file
> make test
cat: file: No such file or directory
123
File:
```

Is there some simple way to prevent the unwanted behavior, and get the following kind of result?

```
> rm file
> make test
123
File: 123
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use `make`'s `$(shell ...` syntax here.  Just use a backtick `...` sequence to invoke `cat` directly...

```
test:
        @echo 123 >> file
        @cat file
        @echo "File: "`cat file`
```

Or, if your version of `echo` supports the option to suppress the trailing newline...

```
test:
        @echo 123 >> file
        @cat file
        @echo -n "File: "; cat file
```

Comment: And that will even work in `make` implementations other than GNU's, which `$(shell ...)` will not do.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some simple way to prevent the unwanted behavior

This is expected and documented behaviour. If that's not what you want, you mustn't use `$(shell)` at all.

```
test:
    @echo 123 >> file
    @cat file
    @printf "File: "
    @cat file
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape your dollars in Makefile and use shell's own subprocess facility, `$(command)`.

```
test:
    echo "zzz" > z
    echo "$$(cat z)"
```