# Prevent execution of command shell in a Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile, gnu-make

The example below define a variable called `GUNICORN_PID_FILE`, this variable run the command `cat` to obtain the PID inside the file.

```
SHELL := /bin/sh

GUNICORN_PID_FILE := gunicorn.pid
GUNICORN_PID = "$(shell cat ${GUNICORN_PID_FILE})"
```

The issue is when the file `gunicorn.pid` not exists.

```
cat: gunicorn.pid: No such file or directory
```

Have a way to prevent this issue?

Comment: The instruction `shell` runs every time that I call the `Makefile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56158578/4173913) works like a charm. Simple use of a subprocess:

```
GUNICORN_PID = "$$(cat ${GUNICORN_PID_FILE})"
```